# The number of pairs $(A,B)$ of subsets of a set $X$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. For subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, write $A \oplus B = (A \cup B) - (A \cap B)$ (symmetric difference). Fix a nonempty subset $C$ of $X$. How many pairs $(A, B)$ of subsets of $X$ are there such that $A \oplus B = C$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I mean, how many ordered pairs $(A, B),~A, B~ \subseteq X$ will give $A \oplus B = C$, for a particular $C (\neq \phi) \subseteq X$

Comment: it is giving as $2^{n-1}$, is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assume that $X$ is finite. Otherwise the answer won't be finite.

Choosing $2$ subsets of $X$ is equivalent to choosing a list $(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$ of disjoint subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$ (the order matters). Informally, $A_1$ corresponds to $A - B$, $A_2$ corresponds to $A \cap B$, $A_3$ corresponds to $B - A$, and $A_4$ corresponds to $X - A - B$.

We would like all such partitions $(A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$ of $X$ such that $A_1 \cup A_3 = C$ and $A_2 \cup A_4 = X - C$. Note then that $A_1$ can be any subset of $C$ and $A_3$ is determined by $A_1$. Likewise, $A_2$ can be any subset of $X -C$ and $A_4$ is determiend by $A_2$. So there are $2^{|C|}$ options for $A_1$ and $2^{|X- C|}$ options for $A_2$. So the answer is $2^{n} 2^{n - c} = 2^{2n - c}$, where $n = |X|$ and $c = |C|$.

This formula applies just as well when $C = \emptyset$, though it's not part of the problem.